# radial gradients for multiple arcs in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, radial-gradients

I have the following arc diagram:

[image]

I would like to add a gradient to each of the individual arcs, that flows from the *outer radius* to the *inner radius* of each individual arc.

I am guessing that I will need to create an individual gradient for each arc?

```
let radius = 100;

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {

  let grad = defs.append('radialGradient')
       .attr('id', 'mygrad' + i)
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
          .attr('cx', '0')
    .attr('cy', '0')
    .attr('r', radius)

  grad.append('stop')
       .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');

  grad.append('stop')
       .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'blue');

  let arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius( radius )
    .innerRadius( radius - 50)
    .startAngle( degToRad(-90) )
    .endAngle( degToRad(90) );

  g.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', `url(#${'mygrad' + i })`)
    .attr('stroke', 'lightgrey');

  radius += 50;
}
```

[image]

---

```
let grad = defs.append('radialGradient')
       .attr('id', 'mygrad' + i)
    .attr('r', '80%')

  grad.append('stop')
       .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');

grad.append('stop')
   .attr('offset', '100%')
  .attr('stop-color', 'blue');
```

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ivan_bacher/pen/vvyrJG)

Comment: You have 5 gradients but you are using only 1. Change .attr('fill', `url(#${'mygrad' + **1** })`) with .attr('fill', `url(#${'mygrad' + **i** })`) line 42

Comment: ups. Ok fixed it and updated the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG 2 adds a [`fr`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/pservers.html#RadialGradientElementFRAttribute) attribute. That makes it possible to define an inner start radius for a gradient. In conjunction with the possibility to quote gradient definitions within other definitiions, your code can be rewritten as

```js
let width = 800;
let height = 800;

let svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

let defs = svg.append('defs');

let g = svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`);

let radius = 100;
    
let gradcolors = defs.append('radialGradient')
    .attr('id', 'gradcolors')
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('cx', '0')
    .attr('cy', '0')

gradcolors.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');

gradcolors.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'blue');

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    let grad = defs.append('radialGradient')
        .attr('id', 'mygrad' + i)
        .attr('href', '#gradcolors')
        .attr('fr', radius - 50)
        .attr('r', radius)

    let arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius( radius )
        .innerRadius( radius - 50)
        .startAngle( -90 * (Math.PI / 180) )
        .endAngle( 90 * (Math.PI / 180) );

    g.append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', `url(#${'mygrad' + i })`)
        .attr('stroke', 'lightgrey');

    radius += 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg> </svg>
```

Or you use the [`spreadMethod="repeat"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradientElementSpreadMethodAttribute) attribute to define only one gradient with infinitely repeating colors.

```js
let width = 800;
let height = 800;

let svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

let defs = svg.append('defs');

let g = svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`);

let radius = 100;
let radiusWidth = 50;
    
let grad = defs.append('radialGradient')
    .attr('id', 'mygrad')
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('spreadMethod', 'repeat')
    .attr('cx', '0')
    .attr('cy', '0')
    .attr('r', radiusWidth)

grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');

grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'blue');

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    let arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius( radius )
        .innerRadius( radius - 50)
        .startAngle( -90 * (Math.PI / 180) )
        .endAngle( 90 * (Math.PI / 180) );

    g.append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', 'url(#mygrad')
        .attr('stroke', 'lightgrey');

    radius += radiusWidth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg> </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to work in UserSpace Coordinates because the object bounding box is not a nice square, you will get a distorted gradient. Specify the `end-radius` of the gradient (`r`).

Specify the white stop in percent relative to the `end-radius` of the gradient (parameter `r`)

```
  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', `${100*(radius-50)/radius}%`)
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');
```

```js
let width = 800;
let height = 800;

let svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

let defs = svg.append('defs');

let g = svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`);

let radius = 100;

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {

  let grad = defs.append('radialGradient')
    .attr('id', 'mygrad' + i)
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('cx', 0)
    .attr('cy', 0)
    .attr('r', radius);

  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', `${100*(radius-50)/radius}%`)
    .attr('stop-color', 'white');

  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', 'blue');

  let arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius( radius )
    .innerRadius( radius - 50)
    .startAngle( degToRad(-90) )
    .endAngle( degToRad(90) );

  g.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', `url(#${'mygrad' + i })`)
    .attr('stroke', 'lightgrey');
  radius += 50;
}

//helpers
function degToRad( deg ) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```