# D3.js: Create a Pie Chart Where Each Slice Has a Different Radial Gradient Radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, radial-gradients

I'm back trying to construct another D3.js chart, this time, a type of Pie Chart with 3 slices.  That's simple enough, but this chart has to have radial gradients on each piece.  Again, maybe not too difficult.  The hard part is that each "piece" has a different radius.
Here's the basic gist of it:

[image]

I started a prototype on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/qBBwjmd).  Here's the gradient part:

```
var radialGradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "radial-gradient");

radialGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#fff");

radialGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");
```

If you can add another gradient on one of the two sides with a smaller radius, I think that I could take it from there.

Edit:  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851904/radial-gradients-for-multiple-arcs-in-d3) is not far removed from my own.  Just not sure how to apply it to my pie pieces.

Edit 2:  [Here](https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/oNNOeop?editors=0011)'s my 2nd prototype.  Not bad if I say so myself.  Any thoughts?

Comment: *"Feel free to mock something in Codepen or JSFiddle!"*. Well, that's quite some work. Why don't **you** create a basic pie chart? Then, we just need to tweak the arc generator, based on the logic for the radius (which you'll need to describe).

Comment: I added a prototype in Codepen now.